# Android 11 Api 30 with Xamarin Essentials Take Photo and save to device

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, save

Is it possible to take a photo using Xamarin Essentials with Android 11 - Api 30 and save it to the device? I have used Xam.Media.Plugin in the past to do this. But I would prefer to only use Xamarin Essentials. I currently have my App taking photos and then programmatically uploading each photo to Azure (which is working well). However, I also want to save a copy of the photo to the device as a backup when internet connectivity is poor, as is regularly the case for my users. The below code doesn't catch and display both alerts below, however nothing is saved to my device. My  code is included below:

```
        private async void TakePhoto()
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Camera started");

                string fN = "RI-" + Asset_ID.Text + lblUniqueName.Text + ".jpg";

                var file = await MediaPicker.CapturePhotoAsync();

                if (file == null)
                    return;

                var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
                content.Add(new StreamContent(await file.OpenReadAsync()), "file", fN);

                string directory = Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) + "/pictures";
                string filePath = Path.Combine(directory, fN);

                DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(directory);
                if (!info.Exists)
                {
                    info.Create();
                }

                Stream fileStream = await file.OpenReadAsync();
                await DisplayAlert("1", "Stream Read", "OK");
                using (FileStream outputFileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    fileStream.CopyTo(outputFileStream);
                }
                await DisplayAlert("2", "Stream Saved", "OK");
                var httpClient = new HttpClient();

                var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("https://tasmanoperationsportal.azurewebsites.net/UploadFile", content);

                Console.WriteLine("App Returned");
                await DisplayAlert("Successful", "Photo uploaded to the cloud", "OK");
            }
            catch
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Unsuccessful", "No internet connectivity, use default camera App and upload later", "OK");
            }
        }
```

AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.tcminspect2_0" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="30" />
    <application android:label="TCmInspect2_0.Android" android:theme="@style/MainTheme" android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" ></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: `CapturePhotoAsync` literally returns a `FileResult` object.  You even save it to a local variable named `file` and call `file.OpenReadAsync()` on it.

Comment: Thanks @Jason, I'm afraid my skills aren't very advanced. Can you tell me how to save the returned FileResult to my local Device?

Comment: fileResult has a FilePath property.  It is already saved on the device

Comment: @Jason when I get the FilePath property of the fileResult it returns /data/user/0/com.companyname.tcminspect2_0/cache. However the file is not here or anyone else on the device. Any ideas?

Comment: how are you determining that?  If `OpenReadAsync()` can open the file and create a stream, the file must be there.   You could also create a stream and then write it to your own file path if you want to have control over its location.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Jason. Can you please show me how to write the stream to a specific file path? This is specifically what I am after. Yes, you are right, it must be there, but when I browse the device storage it is not displaying.

Comment: There are hundreds of existing questions about writing a stream to a file in C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can refer to the official documentation of Media Picker
  (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/media-picker?context=xamarin%2Fandroid&tabs=android)
- According to your code, after you use `string filePath = Path.Combine(directory, fN);`You can use

  ```
  using (var stream = await file.OpenReadAsync())
  using (var newStream = File.OpenWrite(filePath))
      await stream.CopyToAsync(newStream);
  PhotoPath = filePath;
  ```

PhotoPath is the path where the file is saved.Then you only need to call PhotoPath to get the pictures stored locally.

I created a simple example for your reference(I created a button to take a picture and save it to the device):

Here is the cs page code:

```
public string PhotoPath { get; set; } = null;
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var file = await MediaPicker.CapturePhotoAsync();
    await LoadPhotoAsync(file);
    if (file == null)
        return;
    async Task LoadPhotoAsync(FileResult photo)
    {
        // canceled
        if (photo == null)
        {
            PhotoPath = null;
            return;
        }
        // save the file into local storage
        var newFile = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, photo.FileName);
        using (var stream = await photo.OpenReadAsync())
        using (var newStream = File.OpenWrite(newFile))
            await stream.CopyToAsync(newStream);
        PhotoPath = newFile;
        myImg.Source = PhotoPath;//Show on the front page
    }
}
```

Here is the screenshot：

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Wen xu Li - MSFT. Sorry for my lack of understanding, but I'm still a bit confused in regards to PhotoPath is that a property or what is it? If I update my code with what you have above, PhotoPath returns the error that 'it does not exist in the current context. How do i introduce PhotoPath and allow its use?

Comment: It is just a path to record the address, using string type to receive.

Comment: Thanks, I thought this might be the case @Wen xu Li - MSFT. Unfortunately, this code does not save the photo my device application folder

Comment: How did you get certified?You can't directly enter the folder view in the emulator because you don't have permission.

Comment: I am debugging directly to a Samsung Tab A 10.1 device @Wen xu Li - MSFT. When I browse the device storage there is nothing in the Application cache directory after implementing your code and taking photo. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: Stored in the internal storage can not be seen directly, I updated my code, you can try to use the path directly to see if the picture is displayed.

Comment: Thank you, the image is displaying @Wen xu Li - MSFT. I appreciate you help.

Comment: You're welcome, congratulations！